# What are the different input types in HTML?

Tags: html, input, tags

The request is pretty simple. As you know, there are `input` tags in HTML. You can assign a `type` to them. All I want is a simple list of all the different types you can use.

I searched this on google, but no website showed a complete list. I want a place where I can refer to the complete list (here, when someone posts it).

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) should generally suffice.

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

w3schools.com is a great source for learning Web building tools/technologies.

They have provided all the different input types you can use, here check it out
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)